# C++ multiple inheritance polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have a few classes laid out like so:

```
class Shape { 
public:
    virtual void render() const = 0;
    ...other junk...
}
class Animation{
public:
    virtual void animate() = 0;
}

class SomeAnimatedShape : public Shape, public Animation{
    void render() { cout << "render called\n"; }
    void animate() { cout << "animate called\n"; }
}
```

and a `std::vector<Shape*> shapes`.

The Problem is, that I want to call animate on all `Shape*` in `shapes` whose Base class also implements Animation. I tried doing this:

```
std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it = shapes.begin();
while(it != shapes.end())
{
    Animation * a = (Animation *)(*it);
    if (a)
    {
        //a actually isn't nullptr
        a->animate();
    }
    (*it)->render();
    it++;
}
```

but even though it compiles and runs fine and `render()` gets called correctly, `animate()` is never called. What's the problem with this code.

I tried using `a = dynamic_cast<Animation*>(*it)` as well but that just returns null.

Comment: the dynamic_cast answers below are the answer to the question you asked, but the presence of that cast is often an indicator that the design needs a rethink.  Would you consider also storing a vector of all animations, for example?

Comment: I'd suggest using composition instead of inheritance. @AndyNewman suggestion is also good. Storing components (rather then just composite objects) in a vector is an effective and easy optimization.

Comment: @RonakPatel He has two distinct interfaces, and objects which implement both of them.  This is a perfect example of a case where multiple inheritance is really the only correct solution.  There is also the case of mixins.  Your statement that multiple inheritance is not good in practice is simply wrong.

Comment: @AndyNewman He's dealing with polymorphic objects, so putting them in a vector is excluded.

Comment: @RonakPatel Why do simple when you can make it complicated, right?  Multiple inheritance and `dynamic_cast` were added to C++ precisely to support this sort of scenario.  In some different context, he may also have a vector of `Animation`, and need to do something special on those members who support the `Shape` interface.

Comment: I cannot see his code, so I can't redesign it for him.  I imagine a situation in which things which are NOT shapes ARE animations. An animation interface is an excellent way to achieve that. A vector which stores all things implementing the animation interface sounds like a good approach to doing that.

Comment: A completely different approach would be a signal/slot or event passing system, in which an "animate" event is fired and things which care about that register to receive it.  The implementation of that is also, ultimately, going to be something storing a set of all animation objects, but out of sight and perhaps more to some peoples taste.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is what you want here. If it returns null, then that means the object isn't an `Animation`. You haven't shown us how you populated the vector, so we can't tell whether or not it should be.

Comment: You are using pointers, so it should not happen, but it looks like you were converting the `SomeAnimatedShape` to a simple `Shape`. How do you populate vector `shapes` ?

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted has an undefined behaviour, because the C-style cast you are using will always "succeed" in the sense that you will not get a null pointer if your Shape is not actually an animation. No way to tell what comes afterwards, but segmentation fault is a probable option.

Use `dynamic_cast<Animation*>(*it)`! And then the code you wrote seems fine. if `*it` is not an `Animation` object then it will return a nullptr, that is normal.

Maybe you have no `Animation` object in your list ...

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Certainly not; the vector contains pointers, and you can't do a `dynamic_cast` on the address of a pointer.

Comment: Doh. You're right @JamesKanze. I have now deleted my comment, it was pointless. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The Problem is, that I want to call animate on all Shape* in shapes whose Base class also implements Animation. I tried doing this:

According to your code Shape doesn't have a base class. E.g. it is not possible to have a code like this:

```
 shapes.push_back(new Animation());
```

This will prompt a compile error.

Most likely you have :

```
shapes.push_back(new Shape());
```

If you want to have a runtime check then you need to use:

```
Animation * a = dynamic_cast<Animation *>(*it);
```

Comment: True, but it is possible to have `shapes.push_back(new SomeAnimatedShape());`.

Comment: No Problem then. Animation::animate() will be called in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Shape` and your `Animation` does not have any relation.
You should cast your `Shape` in `SomeAnimatedShape` (and then in `Animation` if you want).

```
std::vector<Shape*>::iterator it = shapes.begin();
while(it != shapes.end())
{
   SomeAnimatedShape* a = dynamic_cast<SomeAnimatedShape*>(*it);
   // Animation* a = dynamic_cast<SomeAnimatedShape*>(*it); *Both should work*

   if (a)
      a->animate();

   (*it)->render();
   it++;
}
```

Comment: No, `dynamic_cast<Animation*>` will do a cross-cast, and succeed if the object is derived from `Animation`. There's no need to specify (or even know about) the final derived type(s).